# Dereferencing a pointer to a struct - invalide indirection operand?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I'd like to derefernce a pointer to a struct. This code is compiled using COSMIC compiler and is downloaded to an STM8S microcontroller.

Following is my problem in code:

```
typedef struct GPIO_struct
{
  volatile unsigned char CR1; 
  volatile unsigned char CR2; 
}
GPIO_TypeDef;


void GPIO_DeInit(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx)
{
          // This variable will be used for a testing purpose
          GPIO_TypeDef vGPIO = (GPIO_TypeDef)*GPIOx; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
}

int main(void)
{
    GPIO_TypeDef GPIOY @0x5000; // Reference to an absolute address

    GPIO_DeInit(&GPIOY);
}
```

When I try this code, an error occurs: `invalid indirection operand`. Why does the compiler refuses this code?

Note: the code is based on STM standard library.

**UPDATE:**

I know I can access the struct members using `->` operator but I still want to save the struct members in a variable of the same type as the struct for some testing purpose. I just want to have a snapshot of the registers at this point of time.

**UPDATE 2**

With the code posted above I get another error `invalid cast type`

When I remove the cast, it compiles.

But I don't understand why!! Could someone please explain

Comment: The code in your edited question looks correct. Did you try this: `GPIO_TypeDef vGPIO = *GPIOx;` (without the unnecessary cast)?

Comment: Now that you've modified your code to make the identifiers match, do you in fact still see the same error?  Because I don't.  That is, I took your code (with that change), added a member `ODR` to `struct GPIO_struct`,  defined the symbol `GPIO_ODR_RESET_VALUE`, and commented out the elipsis; the resulting code compiled cleanly for me.

Comment: Won't this code make a copy of GPIOx and therefore any change to vGPIO won't actually update the GPIOx object? Is this what you want?

Comment: what is this `GPIO_TypeDef GPIOY @0x5000;`?

Comment: I compiled with warnings in `gcc`, and there's the problem: `test.c:11:32: warning: ISO C forbids casting nonscalar to the same type [-Wpedantic]`. The other one is: `test.c:18:24: error: stray '@' in program`, but presumably that's an extension of your compiler so not an issue.

Comment: @MartinChekurov That's common on some compilers for embedded direct-to-hardware platforms. It usually means to place something on a specific memory address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original error appears to have arisen from the typographical error in the parameter name.  Presumably the identifier `GPIOX` is defined in your real code, even though you do not present such a declaration in your question, so that you got the "invalid indirection" error instead of one calling out an unknown identifier.

With regard to your update 2, your compiler is being picky, but it is correct.  C requires of cast expressions that

> Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall
>   specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified **scalar** type, and the operand
>   shall have scalar type.

([C2011 6.5.4/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4p2); emphasis added)

In your case, the type name designates a structure type (which is therefore not a scalar type), so your code is non-conforming.  Of course, the cast is altogether unnecessary anyway, because the type of its operand is already the same as the type name specified in the cast.

`gcc` will issue a warning about that for me, but only when the `-pedantic` option is in effect.  Other conforming compilers are free to reject the code instead.